# Date Difference in days and time

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have two dates:

```
Date dt1 = new Date("04/11/2013 11:00:00");//date
Date dt2 = new Date("04/12/2013 11:00:00");
```

Then I process with this code to know how much week between `dt1` and `dt2`

```
double tanggal = (dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
double week= (double) Math.ceil(tanggal/7);
```

I tried to run this code and `the result week is 1.0`, but when the `dt2` is `04/11/2013 11:00:01`  , `the result week is 0.0`.

How to change the result so `the result week is 1.0` if `dt2` is `04/11/2013 11:00:01`? And I want, when the `dt2` until the seventh day or `04/18/2013 11:00:01` the result change to `2.0`. How to do that?

Comment: When time is 12:00:01 shouldn't dt2 be 05/11/2013?

Comment: Evaluating time periods can be dangerous take this with you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177803/android-time-difference-with-joda-time

Comment: What do you want to achieve I guess you can make that thing clear also?

Comment: @Sudhanshu sory i use timeZone Asia/Jakarta, i will edit my sample date question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to round the date difference up to the nearest week.  The reason you're getting 0 if the date-time difference is less than a day is that you round too early.  All you need to do is cast your timestamps to `double` before dividing by the number of milliseconds in the day.  That way you will not loose the time difference of under a day.  Change your code to

```
double tanggal = ((double)(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime())) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
double week= (double) Math.ceil(tanggal/7);
```

This way, your result will be `1.0`.

Comment: i try to put `double` in my timestamps now it works perfectly @Aleks G . the result is 1.0 and the last `04/18/2013 11:00:01` is change result to 2.0. thank you so much.