# How to format a time to a time span?

Tags: android, time

I am getting a time from facebook graph api in json as ( "2013-05-17T06:47:48+0000" ) now i want to convert it to hour span.

For example if a person updated his status at the above time it will show us 2 hour ago or something like that.

So how i covert it to time span??

Help needed.

Comment: you can use `JodaTime` library for efficient results and by using its `Period` class you will be able to get `DurationFieldType.months()` and other formatted result also like years,days,minutes also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this :

```
try {
    long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse("2013-05-17T06:47:48+0200").getTime();
    String timeEllapsed = (delta / 3600000) + "h " + ((delta / 60000) % 60) + "min";
    System.out.println("Time ellapsed : " + timeEllapsed);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: the above time was for fb, now this time is for instagram ("1367911064"), how to deal with this??

Comment: This looks like a timestamp in seconds. In this case, just replace delta by delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - Long.parseLong("1367911064") * 1000;

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be aware that you receive the UTC time from the server. And your users are  all over the world. So you need to get time in UTC on device.

To calculate any time spans I'd recommend you to read this answers: [Android time difference with joda time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177803/android-time-difference-with-joda-time) , that uses JodaTime library.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

you can use `JodaTime` library which is available to download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/).

**Example:**

I have recently created a small demo application and uploaded on my GitHub account.

Have a look at [TimeStampDemo](https://github.com/Joisar/TimeStamp-Demo).It will give you output as you have requested in your question.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

There are methods available in [DateUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html), which Banes talks about 
[here](http://www.senab.co.uk/2013/01/15/snippet-dateutils/). There are some bugs with it in some obscure languages (wasn't able to pinpoint which), so Joda as Mehul suggested might be better if you're localising.